# Do these bagged GUDI pieces make up a single set?

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

I purchased what I thought was some second-hand LEGO today. There was a single plastic bag with the words "***Complete Set***" written on it in sharpie marker. There were 6 sealed polybags inside, all with pieces that look similar in colour (lotsa pinks, purples, browns and whites).

On closer inspection, some of the pieces bear the logo ***"GUDI"*** which I gather is a Chinese manufacturer specialising in '*Lego-style blocks*'. Most of the bags have a number on them (5538.01, 5538.02, etc) but I've not been able to research any GUDI sets that have that number.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Do these pieces comprise a single set (and if so, which one?) or is the bag author a [no-good lying liar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNGZo5gn_tc)?

Comment: What's the trans light blue part in the largest bag? I don't recognize it, but it looks like one of the most distinctive parts here. Maybe if you can identify it, you can go through all sets on Bricklink that include this part.

Comment: @Emil - A) It's not a LEGO set, so bricklink is useless and B) I'm pretty sure that's a generic *"[Brick separator*](https://its-not-lego.blogspot.com/2017/05/gudi-9215-fire-rescuer-building-set.html)" that comes with all GUDI sets.

Comment: Ah, I should have read the complete post. ;) I thought it looked like a brick separator, but was wandering because Lego doesn't have one in this color.

Comment: @Emil - It's frustrating as hell, The bags even have the product code on them, but google is proving useless because GUDI don't seem to publish a catalogue

Comment: Yeah, the pieces tricked me too.   I just half read what was written, glanced at the pieces, and amused the "*GUDI*" stamped on the studded bricks was the "*LEGO*" stamp. I went looking on Bricklink for sets, but oddly couldn't get a hit.  Then I finally stopped, slowed myself down, and finally understood that these were clones.

Answer (score 2):

So, I just *Googled* "*GUDI*" + "*catalogue*" and it brought me to the knockoff's parent company "*Guangdong Xinlexin Education and Culture Co.,Ltd*" or [*Xinlexin.com*](http://www.xinlexin.com/en/).

*Xinlexin's GUDI* product line has two subcategories that match the color scheme of these pieces.

1. *Princess Alice* line.
2. *Modern Girls* line.

Below are pictures from both lines that comprise of around 23 sets.  If you'll notice, each set has many unique identifiable pieces that just don't appear in the current six poly bags above.

The only piece that comes close is that blue translucent piece in *BAG 06*, which sorta looks like the minidoll dress from *[Elena's Studio](http://www.xinlexin.com/en/proView.asp?ID=237)*.

[image]

I don't think it's this dress, but regardless if it were, the poly bags are still short critical pieces to solidly decide on this set.  In fact, we're short critical pieces to decide on any of the other 23 sets.

Another point: We don't know how far back *Xinlexin* website goes when listing their knockoffs.  This could be a complete set before *GUDI* decided to list their wares digitally.

Conclusion: We could safely say that these 6 poly bags are not from any of *Xinlexin's* current line of 23 sets, but due to lack of documentation, we can't say that these pieces *do*, or *do not*, form a complete set.

[image]

[image]

Comment: These appear to be recent sets numbered sequentially from 9012-9020 and 9601-9615. I would assume (based on the number on the bags) that mine are from an earlier set.

Comment: For the record, I'm pretty certain that the blue translucent piece is a "[brick separator](https://its-not-lego.blogspot.com/2017/05/gudi-9215-fire-rescuer-building-set.html)" mentioned on multiple GUDI reviews.

Comment: I've emailed Xinlexin. Hopefully they can shed some light.

Comment: For the record, they didn't email me back, despite several tries.